# add something next to the array objects in python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a string like :

```
A="2+3+4"
```

I want to split it so I need to add blank next to the +

```
A="2 + 3 + 4"
A=A.split()
A=["2","+","3","+","4"]
```

How i can add blanks?
Thanks!

Comment: Expected output? A string or a list?

Comment: If `A="2+3+4"` and you want it to be `"2 + 3 + 4"` just do `A = A.replace('+', ' + ')`.

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing this...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either replace "+" with " +  " and split it into a list:

```
A="2+3+4"
A=A.replace('+', " + ")
A=A.split()
```

Or even easier:

```
A="2+3+4"
A=list(A)
```

Note, however, that the second method splits every character apart from each other.

So doing that for `A="123+456"` would result into `['1','2','3','+','4','5','6']` instead of `['123','+','456']`, so the first one might suit you better.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> print (A.replace('+',' + ').split()),
['2', '+', '3', '+', '4']
```

the why:  split method:
Python 3.2.2

```
>>> A="2+3+4"
>>> print (A.split()),     Org result = ['2+3+4']
```

the result you want is `['2','+','3','+','4']`

you get the Org result, because the default `split` character is whitespace,
ref:   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

what if you specified  "+" as your split character ?

```
>>> print (A.split('+')),   ['2', '3', '4']   almost but not quite !

>>> print (A.replace('+',' + ')),    2 + 3 + 4
```

so if we combine them...

```
>>> print (A.replace('+',' + ').split())
['2', '+', '3', '+', '4']
```

which is the result I imagine you want.